# How can I know exact font colors for Default/Classic Theme in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I would like to find the exact font colors for ***Default/Classic Theme*** in ***Eclipse IDE for Java Developers, Mars.1***

Is there any documentation for that? 
Can I find the color values in any config/settings files?

I tried to look for the same theme on http://www.eclipsecolorthemes.org/ but I was not able to find the same theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Color values are in the CSS files for the theme. These are in the `css` folder in the `org.eclipse.ui.themes` plugin's directory in the `plugins` directory of the Eclipse installation.

Comment: How do you export eclipse default/classic theme to xml file?

Comment: @tpsaitwal I don't know of a way to do that